# react-facebook-login scope not allowing email information

Tags: reactjs, facebook

I'm trying to use [react-facebook-login](https://github.com/keppelen/react-facebook-login) to authenticate users, but I need to access the user's email. This should be doable via the scope parameter, but it doesn't work. There are multiple [issues](https://github.com/keppelen/react-facebook-login/issues/263) about this subject on Github going back years that haven't been addressed.

My question is - is there a way to modify/override this package to accommodate this (it appears the scope parameter is simply not added to the popup url), since it looks good otherwise? I have no idea how to patch or override node modules.

Alternatively, what is the absolute easiest way to implement this - is getting dirty with the Javascript SDK the only way, or are there better packages?

```
<FacebookLogin
            appId="myappid"
            autoLoad={true}
            onClick={componentClicked}
            callback={responseFacebook}
            scope="public_profile,name,email"
        />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using this package instead which works as intended:
https://github.com/seeden/react-facebook

Answer (score 0):

The Package has no issue your app does, you need permission to access such information, while in development you can get the the information's just fine but be aware in  a recent change in facebook graph api now in order to access user email you must ask for email `Advanced Access` you can do that by going to your app dashboard

`https://developers.facebook.com/apps/appId`

in the left panel click `App Review` and select `Permission And Futures` there search for email and click `Get Advanced Access` Clear your browser cache and you good to go

Comment: Yes I have done that. If I take the url of the generated popup and add ?scope=email it works, so for some reason the package isn't adding the correct parameters

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has the same issue where you can't access the email, go to your app dashboard in facebook dev site.

Go to use cases > customize > permissions

You might need to click the add button next to email